# SQLAlchemy: modifications to other object in same table before insert are not persisted

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add an event listener to a table that sets the previously inserted row to inactive (active=False). I can see that during the run, the previous_date object is changed and the property active is set to False (I used breakpoints). However, after the insert is committed I only see the new row in the database. The active property of the previous_date object has not changed. Why is this? See code below
models.py:

```py
binded_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class ScenarioTrainingSchedule(Base):
    __tablename__ = "scenario_training_schedule"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    scenario_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
    training_date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    creation_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

def update_previous_training_date_activity(mapper, connection, target):
    session = binded_maker.object_session(target)
    if session is not None:
        previous_date = (
            session.query(ScenarioTrainingSchedule)
            .filter(ScenarioTrainingSchedule.scenario_id == target.scenario_id)
            .filter(ScenarioTrainingSchedule.active == 1)
            # .order_by(TrainingDate.training_date.desc())
            .first()
        )

        if previous_date:
            attributes.set_committed_value(previous_date, "active", False)
```

database.py:

```py
binded_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = binded_maker()
```

Other service file that imports the session from database.py and inserts new ScenarioTrainingSchedule:

```py
def insert_scenario_training_date(company_id, scenario_name, scenario_date):
    try:
        company_id = int(company_id)
        training_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(scenario_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        training = ScenarioTrainingSchedule(
            company_id=company_id, scenario_id=scenario_name, training_date=training_date
        )

        session.add(training)
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        logging.error(e)
```

Comment: What is `attributes`?

Comment: @JohnGordon attributes is imported from sqlalchemy.orm

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are trying to use a mapper event to do the update, but mapper events can't do this:

> However, the flush plan which represents the full list of every single INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statement to be emitted has already been decided when these events are called, and no changes may be made at this stage¹.

Instead, you can use a [before flush event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_events.html#before-flush). The code is a little more complicated - you need to find the new inserts in `session.new` - but it does what you want.

```py
@sa.event.listens_for(Session, 'before_flush')
def update_previous_training_date_activity(session, flush_context, instances):
    # Find newly inserted instances.
    scenario_ids = [
        x.scenario_id
        for x in session.new
        if isinstance(x, ScenarioTrainingSchedule)
    ]
    # Find corresponding "previous" instances and update them.
    previous = session.query(ScenarioTrainingSchedule).filter(
        sa.and_(
            ScenarioTrainingSchedule.active,
            ScenarioTrainingSchedule.scenario_id.in_(scenario_ids),
        )
    )
    for scenario_training_schedule in previous:
        scenario_training_schedule.active = False
```

---

¹ From the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_events.html#mapper-level-flush-events). If you have warnings enabled, you will see that a mapper event that attempts such an update will emit this warning:

> SAWarning: Identity map already had an identity for (<class '**main**.ScenarioTrainingSchedule'>, (2,), None), replacing it with newly flushed object.   Are there load operations occurring inside of an event handler within the flush?